# Should I use mean centering or not?

Tags: centering

I am using a logistic regression model. I want to see interaction effect of a continuous Independent variable on the relationship of another binary independent variable and the dependent variable(DV is also binary). Should I use the direct product of the continuous and the binary variable or I should first do mean-centering for the continuous variable in my case?

Just to add here, I have tried both techniques and getting better results with mean-centered DV but I want to know if I should also do mean-centering for binary variables or not?

Answer (score 3):

Don't center the binary variable. That just makes your interpretation more complicated, and the only reason to center a variable is (nowadays) to help the interpretation. It used to be that centering made it easier for computers to estimate the model, but algorithms have improved sufficiently to make that no longer an issue for most models, and even then centering a *binary* variable would not have helped.

I claimed that the difference in the models is only a matter of interpretation, but otherwise the two models are completely equivalent. This is best discussed using an example. I use Stata, because that is the package I am most familiar with, but this is about interpretation of results, so the discussion applies to any package. First I open some example data, and do some preliminary preparations. In particular I prepared a centered version of the variable grade. Grade is the level of education attained by the respondents measured in years.

In this case I chose not to center at the mean, but at the value 12. This is US data, so 12 years of education corresponds to having finished highschool. Centering at meaningful values within the range of the data is usually preferable over centering at the mean. First, it is clearer to your audience who you are talking about when saying "someone who finished highschool" than "someone with mean level of education". Second, it makes it easier to replicate your results with different data, as the mean will change (a bit) from dataset to dataset, but 12 will remain 12.

```
. // open example data
. sysuse nlsw88, clear
(NLSW, 1988 extract)

.
. // prepare the data
. gen byte highoc = occupation < 3 if !missing(occupation)
(9 missing values generated)

. label variable highoc "high occupation"

. label define highoc 1 "higher" ///
>                     0 "lower"

. label value highoc highoc

.
. label define south 0 "non-South" 1 "South"

. label value south south
.
. // create a centered version of grade
. gen grade_c = grade - 12
(2 missing values generated)

. label var grade_c "current grade completed (centered at 12)"
```

Next I estimated a logit model with the original grade variable (without centering). So the constant refers to the odds of being a union member for someone with all 0s on the explanatory variables, so a single person not from the South, with 0 years of education in a lower occupation. For such persons we expect 0.09 union members for every non-union member. For people with 0 years of education this odds increases by a factor 1.39 (or $[1.39-1]\times 100\%=39\%$) if one moves to the South. We needed to add "for people with 0 years of education", because we included the interaction term between south and grade. For every year additional information this effect of south decreases by a factor 0.92 (or $[0.92-1]\times100\%=-8\%$)

```
. logit union i.south##c.grade i.highoc i.married, or base nolog

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =      1,867
                                                LR chi2(5)        =     102.23
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -990.16645                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0491

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        union | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        south |
   non-South  |          1  (base)
       South  |   1.386257   .8400857     0.54   0.590     .4226752    4.546534
              |
        grade |   1.155084   .0340266     4.89   0.000     1.090282    1.223738
              |
south#c.grade |
       South  |    .922549   .0414072    -1.80   0.072     .8448596    1.007382
              |
       highoc |
       lower  |          1  (base)
      higher  |   .4300277    .060926    -5.96   0.000     .3257608    .5676675
              |
      married |
      single  |          1  (base)
     married  |   .7222853   .0826679    -2.84   0.004     .5771464    .9039232
              |
        _cons |   .0946328     .03824    -5.83   0.000     .0428628    .2089308
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: _cons estimates baseline odds.
```

Someone with 0 years of education is pretty extreme in the US, so what would be the effect of south for someone who finished highschool (12 years of education)? Here is how you could compute that in Stata. You see that the odds of being a union member is a factor .53 smaller in the South (or the odds changes by -47%).

```
. lincom 1.south + 12*1.south#c.grade, or

 ( 1)  [union]1.south + 12*[union]1.south#c.grade = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       union | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |   .5268865   .0686721    -4.92   0.000      .408108    .6802351
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Similarly, we could compute the baseline odds for a single person from the non-South, a lower occupation, *and who finished highschool* instead of having 0 years of education. We can see that for such a person we expect to find .53 union members for every non-union member.

```
. lincom _cons + 12*grade, or

 ( 1)  12*[union]grade + [union]_cons = 0

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       union | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         (1) |    .533833   .0598071    -5.60   0.000     .4285905    .6649184
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This way of getting more meaningful results is tedious and errors can easily be made. A simple way of avoiding that is to use the centered version of the grade variable. Notice that the log-likelihood, and all coefficients are the same as in the previous model except for the coefficients for the constant and the main effect of grade. Moreover, these two are exactly the same as the coefficients we computed afterwards. So the two models are equivalent, but the one with the centered version of grade is easier to interpret.

```
. logit union i.south##c.grade_c i.highoc i.married, or base nolog

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =      1,867
                                                LR chi2(5)        =     102.23
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -990.16645                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0491

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          union | Odds Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          south |
     non-South  |          1  (base)
         South  |   .5268865   .0686721    -4.92   0.000      .408108    .6802351
                |
        grade_c |   1.155084   .0340266     4.89   0.000     1.090282    1.223738
                |
south#c.grade_c |
         South  |    .922549   .0414072    -1.80   0.072     .8448596    1.007382
                |
         highoc |
         lower  |          1  (base)
        higher  |   .4300277    .060926    -5.96   0.000     .3257608    .5676675
                |
        married |
        single  |          1  (base)
       married  |   .7222853   .0826679    -2.84   0.004     .5771464    .9039232
                |
          _cons |    .533833   .0598071    -5.60   0.000     .4285905    .6649184
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Note: _cons estimates baseline odds.
```